# Getting error while implementing angular2-tree-component in Angular 2 final release

Tags: angular

I have installed node-4.6.0 version and npm version is 3.10.8 which seems stable version for Angular 2 final release.
I am doing small POC on creating dynamic tree structure and drag and drop nodes from one component to another. For that I have installed module Angular2-tree-component with below command:
**npm install --save angular2-tree-component**

After installation, I have updated app.component.ts with below code (as I am following [this](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/getting-started) link:):

App.component.ts:

```
import { Component,NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeModule } from 'angular2-tree-component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [TreeModule]
})

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: '<Tree [nodes]="nodes"></Tree>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'child2.2',
          children: [
            { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
```

App.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { TreeModule } from 'angular2-tree-component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    TreeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**While starting the servers, it is giving me error like:**

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './<Tree [nodes]="nodes"></Tree>' in 'C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app'
resolve './<Tree [nodes]="nodes"></Tree>' in 'C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app'
  using description file: C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    using description file: C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/<Tree [nodes]="nodes"></Tree>)
      as directory
        C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app\<Tree [nodes]="nodes"><\Tree> doesn't exist
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app\<Tree [nodes]="nodes"><\Tree> doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app\<Tree [nodes]="nodes"><\Tree>.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app\<Tree [nodes]="nodes"><\Tree>.js doesn't exist
[C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app\<Tree [nodes]="nodes"><\Tree>]
[C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app\<Tree [nodes]="nodes"><\Tree>]
[C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app\<Tree [nodes]="nodes"><\Tree>.ts]
[C:\Stash\angularTreeComponent\TreeComponent\src\app\<Tree [nodes]="nodes"><\Tree>.js]
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 45:22-64
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

I am not sure what steps I am missing to use angular2-tree-component. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we change structure of nodes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [TreeModule]
})
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: '<Tree [nodes]="nodes"></Tree>'
})
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

This part is incorrect, you are only specifying a component class, but no module.
There should be an `app.module.ts` next to your `app.component.ts` file, which should look like this:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, TreeModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Notice that I import `TreeModule` here, this means you can use that component inside components that belong to AppModule.

Remember that to use TreeComponent in another module than AppModule, you will have to import it there as well.

Comment: I have made changes in app.module.ts as you mentioned but still the same error, below are both files, app.component.ts and app.module.ts:

Comment: You should remove the `NgModule` decorator from your component.

Comment: I am updating both the files in my question, seems I cant paste code here.

Comment: I removed NgModule from app.component.ts but still the same issue. Am I doing some blunder with the logic.

Comment: Your error happens on `line 45` in `app.component.ts`. Please paste that line into your question.

Comment: There are only 34 lines as part of app.component.ts, I have pasted complete files

Comment: I got the solution, I coded templateURL instead of template. It worked now. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You have not included `AppModule` class in your `app.component.ts` :

```
import { Component,NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeModule } from 'angular2-tree-component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: '<Tree [nodes]="nodes"></Tree>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  // your component code
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [TreeModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

If above changes not work then try to check by adding `bootstrap : [AppComponent]` in `@NgModule` metadata.